# Kafka consumer worked failed if the head two kafka process are stoped also

Tags: apache-kafka

**1. env**

Kafka version: 0.11.0.1.

**2. Problem desc**

No matter how many kafka nodes, if stop the head two kafka process, then, consumer can't get message from kafka(producer can send message to kafka), after check, the head two kafka nodes are consumer group coordinators, if one hangs, another will go on to work, if hang both, consumer doesn't work, report error: Offset commit failed, This is not the correct coordinator.

**3. My question.**

Is My tested result correct? if tested result is correct, it seems kafka doesn't support heigh available.

if my tested result is wrong, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i was found, because __consumer_offsets's replication factor is configured to 2(the head two kafka nodes), so no matter how many kafka nodes, if the head two kafka nodes are down, will report error: commit offset failed.